# Must ddply use all possible combinations of the splitting variable(s), or only observed?

Tags: r, plyr, cardinality

I have a data frame called `thetas` containing about 2.7 million observations.

```
> str(thetas)
'data.frame':   2700000 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ rho_cnd   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pct_cnd   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sx        : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ model     : Factor w/ 7 levels "dN.mN","dN.mL",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ estTheta  : num  -1.58 -1.716 0.504 -2.296 0.98 ...
 $ trueTheta : num  0.0962 -3.3913 3.6006 -0.1971 2.1906 ...
 $ estError  : num  -1.68 1.68 -3.1 -2.1 -1.21 ...
 $ trueAberSx: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I would like to use `ddply`, or some similar function, to sum the error of estimation (the column `estError` in my data frame), but where the sums are within each condition of my simulation. The problem is, I don't have a simple way to combine values from the other columns of this data frame to uniquely identify all those conditions. To be more specific: the column `model` contains 7 possible values. Three of these possible values are only matched up with one possible value in each of `rho_cnd` and `pct_cnd`, while the other four possible values of `model` are matched up with 6 possible pairings of values in `rho_cnd` and `pct_cnd`.

The obvious solution, I know, would be to go back and make a variable that uniquely identifies all the conditions that I would need to identify here, so that the following code would work:

```
> sums <- ddply(thetas,.(condition1,condition2,etc.),sum(estError))
```

But I just don't want to go back and recreate how this data frame is built. Right now I have two data frames created with two separate calls to `expand.grid` that are then `rbind`ed and sorted to create a data frame listing all valid conditions, but even if I kept those few lines of code in I'm not sure how to reference them with `ddply`. I would rather not even use this solution, but I will if necessary.

```
> conditions 
   models rhos pcts
1   dN.mN  0.0 0.00
2   dN.mL  0.0 0.00
3   dN.mH  0.0 0.00
4   dL.mN  0.1 0.01
12  dL.mN  0.1 0.02
20  dL.mN  0.1 0.10
8   dL.mN  0.2 0.01
16  dL.mN  0.2 0.02
24  dL.mN  0.2 0.10
5   dL.mL  0.1 0.01
13  dL.mL  0.1 0.02
21  dL.mL  0.1 0.10
9   dL.mL  0.2 0.01
17  dL.mL  0.2 0.02
25  dL.mL  0.2 0.10
6   dH.mN  0.1 0.01
14  dH.mN  0.1 0.02
22  dH.mN  0.1 0.10
10  dH.mN  0.2 0.01
18  dH.mN  0.2 0.02
26  dH.mN  0.2 0.10
7   dH.mH  0.1 0.01
15  dH.mH  0.1 0.02
23  dH.mH  0.1 0.10
11  dH.mH  0.2 0.01
19  dH.mH  0.2 0.02
27  dH.mH  0.2 0.10
```

Any advice for better code and/or more efficiency? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Why doesn't `ddply(thetas,.(model,rho_cnd,pct_cnd),...)` work?

Comment: @joran You are right -- I assumed that, much like `expand.grid()`, using what you suggest would result in `ddply` pairing together all possible combinations of my three column condition indicators, rather than using only the actual/observed pairings. I just tested it out and you are right that this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment that `ddply(thetas,.(model,rho_cnd,pct_cnd),...)` should work.  If certain combinations of those variables don't show up, ddply(..., .drop=TRUE) will ensure that the unobserved combinations don't show up.

However, if you wanted to avoid ddply looking through some of the non-existant combinations, you could try something like the following:

```
#newCond <- apply(thetas[,c("model", "rho_cnd", "pct_cnd")], 1, paste, collapse="_")
newCond <- do.call(paste, thetas[,c("model", "rho_cnd", "pct_cnd")], sep="_") #as suggested by baptiste
thetas2 <- cbind(thetas, newCond)
```

I admit, the above code might run slowly for you, so I'm not sure it's what you want. But from there you should be able to use ddply() with .variables=newCond.

Furthermore, because you're returning only a single number for each subset of the data, you could just use aggregate, if you wanted.

```
sums <- aggregate(thetas2[,"estError"], by=thetas2[,"newCond"], colSums)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: you don't need apply; paste is vectorised (something like `do.call(paste, theta[,...])` should do)

Comment: That doesn't work for me:
(1)`test <- matrix(1:15, ncol=3)`
(2)`apply(test, 1, paste, collapse="_")`
(3)`do.call(paste, list(t(test), collapse="_"))` They aren't the same.  How do I get it to work?

Comment: it works with a list such as a data.frame, `do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(test), sep="_"))`

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @rbatt Yes, you are joran are both correct that this works. Thank you for pointing it out!